# Web-Service: How to authenticate users with the SQL Server database table using VB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, web-services, ado.net

Can somebody tell me how to authenticate users with the SQL Server database table using VB as a web service. I managed to connect to the SQL server via this VB code;

```vb
Public Sub ConnectToSQL()
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Try
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=TestDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=421"
            con.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting to SQL Server." & ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close() 'Whether there is error or not. Close the connection.
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Any one ?Thank you in advance.

Comment: The normal approach is to authenticate the web service to the database.  It's nearly impossible to authenticate the end user to the database due to [delegation of trust issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981414/asp-net-windows-authentication-to-sql-server).

Comment: May be I am not cleared my question, simply speaking that i have to add users and their password in the database (How to do that in VB? in the above code?) Second is that how to use these credential to access the application via web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would recommend that you first go through basic tutorials on  SQL server as well as ADO.Net and then post questions. This will help in making your concepts clear as well as any help can be provided in more focused, problem areas. BTW, no hard feelings, just want you to be comfortable on programming. :)**

Step 1 :

Create relevant database tables. These may include a `users` table and other tables such as `roles`, etc...
**EDIT :** You can use SQL scripts to create tables in DB. Please find a sample below.

```
-- Sample Table Creation and Index Creation script for MCIS-4423
-- This script is designed to be "re-runnable", but you need to be careful, 
-- Since this will DROP the table, which would be bad if it was an existing table with data

-- Make sure you are in the correct database
USE [AdventureWorks]
GO

-- Drop Check Constraint
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.check_constraints WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[CK_Team_TeamID]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Team]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Team] DROP CONSTRAINT [CK_Team_TeamID]
GO

-- Drop Table
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Team]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Team]
GO

-- Create Table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Team](
    [TeamID] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [TeamName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [City] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [StateCode] [char](2) NULL,
    [PostalCode] [char](5) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Team] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  
(
    [TeamID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- Add Check Constraint
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Team]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Team_TeamID] CHECK  (([TeamID] like '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]'))
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Team] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Team_TeamID]
GO

-- Drop index if it exists
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Team]') AND name = N'IX_Team_TeamName')
DROP INDEX [IX_Team_TeamName] ON [dbo].[Team] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )
GO

-- Add non-clustered index on StateCode column
-- Use ONLINE = ON if you have Developer or Enterprise Edition
-- Use MAXDOP = 2 (set to roughly 25% of the number of CPU cores to keep index creation from affecting performance)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Team_TeamName] ON [dbo].[Team] 
(
    [StateCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = ON, MAXDOP = 2, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Please note that this sample is copied from http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2007/09/27/sample-table-and-index-creation-script-for-sql-server-2005/ and all credit related to its content goes to the author who wrote it.**

Step 2 :

Write SQL query to find a user based on his `username` and `password`. You may go for password encryption, but that is out of scope for current question.
**EDIT :** Sample query can be as follows :

```
SELECT username FROM users
WHERE username=@username and password=@password
```

You can read through `SqlCommand` documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) to understand how to add parameters to a query.

Step 3 :

Add `WebMethod`s so that you can create `users` records in database. Use `SqlCommand` to fire `INSERT` queries on your database tables.
**EDIT :** Read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_example.asp) for a sample on how to write web services in VB.Net. And yes, you already know now, how to use `SqlCommand` to fire SQL queries, do the same for `INSERT` queries too.

Step 4 :

Create a `WebMethod`, that validates a user. For this, use `SqlCommand` object to fire your query written in Step 2. If you get a row as a result, the user is valid.
**EDIT :** Refer instructions to above steps and you should be able to create this on your own.

Hope I am clear enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have all that in my mind, and in steps it really helps me, but can you provide me some code examples to these steps. Thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer to include samples. Please read thoroughly and mark as answer if you find it helpful.